# How to prevent lost updates on the views in a distributed CQRS/ES system?

Tags: cqrs, high-availability, event-sourcing

I have a CQRS/ES application where some of the views are populated by events from multiple aggregate roots.

I have a `CashRegisterActivated` event on the `CashRegister` aggregate root and a `SaleCompleted` event on the `Sale` aggregate root. Both events are used to populate the `CashRegisterView`. The `CashRegisterActivated` event creates the `CashRegisterView` or sets it active in case it already exists. The `SaleCompleted` event sets the last sale sequence number and updates the cash in the drawer.

**When two of these events arrive within milliseconds, the first update is overwritten by the last one. So that's a lost update.**

I already have a few possible solutions in mind, but they all have their drawbacks:

1. Marshal all event processing for a view or for one record of a view on the same thread. This works fine on a single node, but once you scale out, things start to get complex. You need to ensure all events for a view are delivered to the same node. And you need to migrate to another node when it goes down. This requires some smart load balancer which is aware of the events and the views.
2. Lock the record before updating to make sure no other threads or nodes modify it in the meantime. This will probably work fine, but it means giving up on a lock-free system. Threads will set there, waiting for a lock to be freed. Locking also means increased latency when I scale out the data store (if I'm not mistaken).

For the record: I'm using Java with Apache Camel, RabbitMQ to deliver the events and MariaDB for the view data store.

Comment: this group is a good source of help and advice on CQRS
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a CQRS/ES application where some of the views in the read model are populated by events from multiple aggregate roots.

That may be a mistake.

Driving a process off of an isolated event.  But composing a view normally requires a history, rather than a single event.

A more likely implementation would be to use the arrival of the events to mark the current view stale, and to use a single writer to update the view from the history of events produced by the aggregate(s) concerned.

> And that requires a smart messaging solution. I thought "Smart endpoints and dumb pipes" would be a good practice for CQRS/ES systems.

It is.  The endpoints just need to be smart enough to understand when they need histories, or when events are sufficient.

A view, after all, is just a snapshot.  You take inputs (X.history, Y.history), produce a snapshot, write the snapshot into your view store (possibly with meta data describing the positions in the histories that were used), and you are done.

The *events* are just used to indicate to the writer that a previous snapshot is stale.  You don't use the event to extend the history, you use the event to tell the writer that a history has changed.

You don't *lose* updates with multiple events, because the event itself, with all of its state, is captured in the history.  It's the history that is used to build the event-sourced view.

Konrad Garus [wrote](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/09/22/writing-an-event-sourced-cqrs-read-model/)

> ... handling events coming from a single source is easier, but more importantly because a DB-backed event store trivially guarantees ordering and has no issues with lost or duplicate messages.

Comment: +1 for marking views stale.
How would you model the cash in a cash drawer given there can be hundreds of sales in a day? I guess making CashRegister or CashDrawer the aggregate root for Sale won't work either. I would still have to marshal all writes on a single thread of a single node. That basically is solution 1. And that requires a smart messaging solution. I thought "[Smart endpoints and dumb pipes](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#SmartEndpointsAndDumbPipes)" would be a good practice for CQRS/ES systems.

Comment: If I understand your edit correctly you would create some kind of intermediate events that describe the changes that would happen to a single view? Still I don't see how you could ensure only a single node consumes these events. And how would you distribute load evenly across all nodes, keeping the pipes dumb?

Comment: Go back to start -- I'm not really showing you solutions to the problem you think you have; I'm trying to show you that you should have a different problem with easier solutions.  No, I'm not creating any intermediate events; I'm building the views by retrieving histories from the book of record.

Comment: Am I correct then that you store the events on the denormaliser to reconstruct the views when they become stale?

Comment: No - I might use caches between the view writer and the book of record to meet a tighter SLA (after all, the events are immutable, and the histories are append only), but the logical design is to fetch histories from the book of record as needed.  For the special case where the current view can be constructed by folding new history into a previous view, I'll store high water marks with the snapshot metadata, but not the events.

Comment: I'm reading a lot of new lingo here. Can you refer to an example that uses a similar architecture?

Comment: @StijnVanBael We use this kind if architecture in the product I'm working on. The Denormalizers listens on events we tell them to subscribe to. When the event arrives, it updates the projection that the event affects. When a user wishes to look at something, we ask the denormalizer for that projection, and present it to the user (with some mapping to make it all Strings so frontend is happy). Each time a user refreshes the page, we query the denormalizer for a fresh version of the projection.

Comment: @Chewtoy our denormalizers work the same way you described. But when we run them active/active and put the systems under pressure, updates get lost because two events for the same projection are processed concurrently by two different nodes.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to detect the when this situation happens, and do a retry.
To do this:

- Add to each table the aggregate version number which is kept up to date
- On each update statement add the following the the where clause "aggr_version=n-1" (where n is the version of the event being processed)
- When the result of the update statement is that no records where modified, it probably means that the event was processed out of order and a retry strategy can be performed

The problem is that this adds complexity and is hard to test. The performance bottleneck is very likely in the database, so a single process with a failover solution will probably be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although I see you ask how to handle these things at scale - I've seen people recommend using a single threaded approach - until such times as it actually becomes a problem - and then address it.
I would have a process manager per view model, draw the events you need from the store and write them single threaded.

Comment: That time when it becomes a problem would be in 3 months. I'd rather not tell my superior it wasn't a problem today so I didn't fix it. Your solution comes down to solution 1, marshalling all events for a view record on a single thread.

Comment: I hear ya,but it is interesting to consider the cost-benefit analysis of whether this is a problem that needs solved, its interesting potentially to include your boss in that discussion.  
Dependent on your technology, you could be processing tens,hundreds or thousands of events per second to update your views,depends on the throughput of the system. 
As for the other problems you see with option 1, what about Competing Consumer, if your process managers operated like that, spreading those consumers over a few nodes for reliability.. check out geteventstore.com

Comment: and i only put it down as an answer as I couldn't see the comment button on the app.

Comment: Currently the system is set up with competing consumers. And because the pipe is dumb, just delivering messages to the consumers round robin, 2 consumers might process a message for the same view record concurrently. This is the lost update problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: ok, so, you want some sort of guaranteed delivery of messages to the consumer, at least once...  maybe this then is the problem to focus on?
I know with the event store, you can set it up so that you have to acknowledge you've processed the message, otherwise it will be redelivered to another consumer, but it wont be delivered to two consumers.
http://docs.geteventstore.com/introduction/3.8.1/competing-consumers/
hopefully, this is some use to you, its good to discuss these things usually :-)

Comment: I've got guaranteed delivery covered. I just need to fix the lost update problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123210/discussion-between-stijn-van-bael-and-mike-d).

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answers of VoiceOfUnreason and StefRave into something I think might work. Populating a view from multiple aggregate roots feels wrong indeed. We have out of order detection with a retry queue. So an event on an aggregate root will only be processed when the last completely processed event is version n-1.

So when I create new aggregate roots for the views that would be populated by multiple aggregate roots (say aggregate views), all updates for the view will be synchronised without row locking or thread synchronisation. We have conflict detection with a retry mechanism on the aggregate roots as well, that will take care of concurrency on the command side. So if I just construct these aggregate roots from the events I'm currently using to populate the aggregate views, I will have solved the lost update problem.

Thoughts on this solution?